# Is it possible to list files from cache directory of another app?

Tags: android, file

As described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), internal storage files are private to application.

But, is there any way just to access list of for ex. cache directory files of another app?

```
Context context = createPackageContext(packageNameOfAnotherApp, 0);
File directory = context.getCacheDir();
directory.listFiles(); // this will return null, as do list()
```

Comment: That is part of internal storage and should be inaccessible to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, for security reasons obviously.
You can only access data of other apps it they have written it to a publicly readable directory, or using a `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless device is rooted and your application has elevated privileges you cannot access private data of other applications directly.